# Get spark Driver ID from within driver

Tags: apache-spark

We're submitting jobs to a standalone cluster in cluster deploy mode (i.e. driver running in Spark) and would like to be able to track the progress of the jobs and instrument them.
In order to do that, we need to know the ID of the driver that Spark assigned to the driver process but I have not seen any way to obtain that information from within the running application, as it is not exposed in any way via the Spark Context (only the application ID is exposed, which is not the same).

Am I missing something or is there really no way to know the driverId from within the executing code?

Comment: don't you have the list of running drivers at the bottom of the main management page of the spark master? I mean go to the spark master management page (ip:8080 or ip:8081) there you should see both running applications and on the bottom of the page the running drivers

Comment: Yes, how does that help? I need to get the driver ID *from within the driver*...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to get the driver ID. However, there is one thing that we can think of doing. Each job once submitted is identified by an Application Id in the Yarn Resource Manager. So, the tracking of the Driver which is running within Application Master (due to cluster mode) may be possible provided you go through the logs related to the Application Master/Yarn/Resource manager/Application id.